# Custom query AFTER rss fetch_feed not working

Tags: query, rss, feed, simplepie

I'm trying to do a custom query after an rss `fetch_feed` but for some reason nothing shows up. The code I'm using to fetch the feed is:

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
      include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

      // Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
      $rss = fetch_feed( 'http://seko.se/feed.rss?rssId=97' );

      if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

          // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 3. 
          $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 3 ); 

          // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
          $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

      endif;
    ?>

    <ul>
        <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
            <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
            <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"
                        title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
                        <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="news-meta-rss">
                      <i class="fi-clock"></i><time datetime="<?php the_date('Y-m-d'); ?>"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

And the query I'm trying to do after this is:

```
<?php
  global $post;
  $args = array( 
    'numberposts' => 2,
    'post_type' => 'nyheter_cpt',
    'category__not_in' => array( 157, 150 ),
    );
  $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
?>

  <div class="large-4 medium-6 small-12 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Läs mer &raquo;</a>
      <ul class="news-meta">
        <li><i class="fi-clock"></i><time datetime="<?php the_date('Y-m-d'); ?>"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time></li>
        <li><i class="fi-torso-female"></i><div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div></li>
      </ul>         
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The query works just fine if I place it above the rss fetch_feed request, but as soon as I place it beneath it nothing shows up. Does anyone have a clue why?

Comment: I changed the query code to:

Comment: Instead of `get_posts($args)` use `new WP_Query($args);` and then add `var_dump($myposts->request);` just beneath it. What is the output?

Comment: Hey, I've done as you suggested and it returned "NULL".

Comment: `NULL` ? That doesn't makes sense. I don't know how to produce that result.

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong with the query itself since its working just fine if I place it above the RSS code. The thing is that I've copied the rss code from the codex so it should be correct. The problem remains even if I remove the header and footer so that no javascripts are loaded. There are no errors showing up in the console as well. I't a real mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be connected to the rss url itself, if I use 'http://seko.se/feed.rss?rssId=97' I can't create new loops beneath it but if I use another url such as 'http://www.wpbeginner.com/feed/' It works.

My original feed works just fine in other readers so I have no idea why it does not work in wordpress.